# formatting data frame using awk

Tags: awk

I have data that look this:

```
$ cat data.tsv
```

```
variant minor_allele    minor_AF    low_confidence_variant  n_complete_samples  AC  ytx beta    se  tstat   pval
1:69569:T:C C   1.90E-04    TRUE    272338  1.04E+02    1.02E+00    -2.48E-02   7.19E-02    -3.44E-01   7.31E-01
1:139853:C:T    T   5.67E-06    FALSE   272338  3.09E+00    1.83E+00    5.00E-01    4.04E-01    1.24E+00    2.16E-01
1:692794:CA:C   C   1.11E-01    FALSE   272338  6.05E+04    -3.35E+02   -3.67E-03   3.34E-03    -1.10E+00   2.71E-01
1:693731:A:G    G   1.16E-01    FALSE   272338  6.32E+04    -4.94E+02   -6.37E-03   3.16E-03    -2.02E+00   4.35E-02
```

And I need them be like this:

```
$ cat newdata.tsv
```

```
snp A1  A2  beta    P   n
1:139853    T   C   5.00E-01    2.16E-01    272338
1:693731    G   A   -6.37E-03   4.35E-02    272338
```

i.e. split the first column on the second and third colon, select and rename five columns, drop the low confidence variants, and keep only biallelic variants with alleles "A", "T", "C" or "G".

Is there a way to do it using awk?

Edited to add: what I managed to do is this:

```
awk < data.tsv -F'[:]' '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4, $5 }' > data1.tsv
```

Which produces this output:

```
$ cat data1.tsv

variant minor_allele    minor_AF    low_confidence_variant  n_complete_samples  AC  ytx beta    se  tstat   pval
         
1   69569   T   C   C   1.90E-04    TRUE    272338  1.04E+02    1.02E+00    -2.48E-02   7.19E-02    -3.44E-01   7.31E-01

1   139853  C   T   T   5.67E-06    FALSE   272338  3.09E+00    1.83E+00    5.00E-01    4.04E-01    1.24E+00    2.16E-01

1   692794  CA  C   C   1.11E-01    FALSE   272338  6.05E+04    -3.35E+02   -3.67E-03   3.34E-03    -1.10E+00   2.71E-01

1   693731  A   G   G   1.16E-01    FALSE   272338  6.32E+04    -4.94E+02   -6.37E-03   3.16E-03    -2.02E+00   4.35E-02
```

And then this:

```
awk < data1.tsv '(NR>1){snp1=$1;snp2=$2;a1=$5;a2=$3;beta=$11;P=$14;n=$8}(NR==1){print "SNP A1 A2 beta P n"}(NR>1 && $7=="FALSE" && (a1=="A"||a1=="C"||a1=="G"||a1=="T") && (a2=="A"||a2=="C"||a2=="G"||a2=="T")) {print snp1":"snp2, a1, a2, beta, P, n}' > newdata.tsv
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
$ cat newdata.tsv


SNP A1 A2 beta P n
1:139853 T C 5.00E-01 2.16E-01 272338
1:693731 G A -6.37E-03 4.35E-02 272338
```

But I still wish for a better way of doing it.

Comment: Nice. Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: generally speaking, assume most people reading this question are not familiar with your specific terms (eg, `drop the low confidence variants,`, `biallelic variants` and `alleles`); for most of us this is just a bunch of data so your chances of getting a workable solution will be based on using terminology most can understand (eg, keep lines where ... the 4th field == `FALSE`; the 1st field (`t1:t2:t3:t4`) has `t3` equal to one of `A` / `C` / `G` / `T`; the 3rd field is equal to one of `A` / `C` / `G` / `T`; etc)

Answer (score 3):

This may be easier with something like Ruby, Perl, Python.

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
alleles=["A", "T", "C", "G"]
csv_options={headers:true, col_sep:"\t"}
puts CSV.generate(**csv_options){|csv|
    csv<<["snp","A1","A2","beta", "P", "n"]
    CSV.parse($<.read, **csv_options).each{|row| 
        ff=row["variant"].split(":")
        if alleles.include?(ff[2]) && row["low_confidence_variant"]=="FALSE"
            csv<<["#{ff[0]}:#{ff[1]}",ff[2],ff[3],
                      row["beta"],row["pval"],row["n_complete_samples"]]
        end
    }    
}    
' file
```

If you want an awk, I would do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; print "snp","A1","A2", "beta", "P" }
{split($1, ff, ":")}
FNR==1 || $4=="TRUE" || index("ATGC", ff[3])==0 {next}
{
    print ff[1] ":" ff[2], ff[3], $2, $8, $11, $5
}' file
```

Or if you want column names in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; print "snp","A1","A2", "beta", "P"}
FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) header[$i]=i; next }
{split($header["variant"], ff, ":")}
$header["low_confidence_variant"]=="TRUE" || index("ATGC", ff[3])==0 {next}
{
    print ff[1] ":" ff[2], ff[3], ff[4], $header["beta"], 
            $header["pval"], $header["n_complete_samples"]
}' file
```

Any of those prints:

```
snp A1  A2  beta    P   n
1:139853    C   T   5.00E-01    2.16E-01    272338
1:693731    A   G   -6.37E-03   4.35E-02    272338
```

Note: It is unclear whether `A2` in you table is the final value from the split of column 1 or the value in column 2...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
% awk -v OFS="\t" '
    BEGIN{print "snp", "A1", "A2", "beta", "P", "n"} 
    NR>1{split($1, ar, ":")
         if(length(ar[3]) < 2 && $4 != "TRUE"){
           print ar[1]":"ar[2], ar[3], ar[4], $8, $11, $5}}' data.tsv
snp A1  A2  beta    P   n
1:139853    C   T   5.00E-01    2.16E-01    272338
1:693731    A   G   -6.37E-03   4.35E-02    272338
```